# Читать данные используя REST API с периодом в 5 секунд и закончить работу после N итераций

Tags: python, циклы, while

Здравствуйте. Мой код берет данные с api одного сайта. Данные числовые, постоянно меняются. Мне необходимо печатать в файл информацию, когда данные соответствуют моему условию и ничего не делать, когда не соответствуют. Цикл должен повторяться 1000 раз с промежутком в 5 секунд.

Вот код: (api для примера)

```
import requests
import json
from datetime import datetime, date, time
import pandas as pd

Kuc = requests.get('https://api.kucoin.com/v1/open/tick')
k = pd.DataFrame(Kuc.json()['data']['LEND-BTC'])
with open("hi.txt", 'a') as hi_file:
  if k > 0.002: 
      print (k, file=hi_file)
```

Я попробовал добавить конструкцию

```
cycle = 0 
while True:
    if.....

    if cycle == 1000:
      break
      time.timesleep(5)
```

Но при таком варианте, данные перестали выводиться, хоть и условие выполняется.
Спасибо!

Comment: `k = pd.DataFrame(Kuc.json()['data']['LEND-BTC'])` - выдает ошибку: `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str`

Comment: в вашем варианте при `break` у вас цикл заканчивается.

Comment: Ошибку выдает, потому что, это не там еще строк кода не хватает, api для примера.

Comment: Я добавил  break, чтобы код заканчивался, когда 1000 циклов пройдет. Не так?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
def get_data(symbol='LEND-BTC', column='changeRate'):
    r = requests.get('https://api.kucoin.com/v1/open/tick')
    if not r.ok:
        r.raise_for_status()
    return (pd.DataFrame(r.json()['data'])
              .query("symbol == @symbol")
              .loc[:, column]
              .iat[0])

cycles = 1000

with open("d:/temp/hi.txt", 'a') as hi_file:        
    for _ in range(cycles):
        k = get_data(symbol='LEND-BTC', column='changeRate')
        if k > 0.002: 
            print(k, file=hi_file)
        time.sleep(5)
```